# Python folium Can't display marker and circle together

Tags: python, folium

I would like to display both marker and circle when toggling the object. Unfortunately, I can't because the single marker is treated as a double one, which you can see in  the image below:

[image]

My code looks like follows:

surv = MarkerCluster(name="Surveyors").add_to(m)
m.add_child(surv)

su1 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(surv, "Jamie Black")
m.add_child(su1)

su13 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(surv, "Lee Anderson")
m.add_child(su13)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
lat = df.at[i, 'lat']
lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
stat = df.at[i,'title']
name = df.at[i,'name']

```
tooltip = df.at[i,'skillset']
surmarker = folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip, icon = 
folium.Icon(color='white', icon='house', prefix='fa', icon_color='green'))
surcircle = folium.Circle([lat,lng], radius=32186, tooltip = sp + ' - Job limits', 
color='darkred', fill=True,  fill_color='darkred', opacity=0.1, fill_opacity=0.1)
popup = '<h5 style="font-weight: 900;">'+str(name)+'</h5>' + str(df.at[i, 'post code'])


if name == "Jamie Black":
        surmarker.add_to(su1)
        surcircle.add_to(su1)
```

I am creating the subgroups and I want to add the marker, which will be visible along with the circle but not separately. When clustered it creates confusion, as people think, that in the given place are 2 objects, whereas it's only one.

Is it possible with folium subgroups?